# Handling lot of items in std::stack 

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Can C++ `std::stack` handle more than 10k int items? And how about its performance?

Comment: without knowing 10K of what items the question is vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance depends on the underlying container used. As already mentioned, `stack` is an adapter, the underlying container can be `deque` (the default), or `vector`, or `list` (all in `std` namespace).

Following is an example of performance comparison. As the type to be stored is not clearly mentioned in the question, I am assuming it to be unsigned int. Feel free to change it per your requirements. The example constructs a stack of 100K items.

Contents of `stack.cpp`

```
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned int Type;

#ifdef USE_VECTOR
typedef std::stack< Type, std::vector< Type > > StackType;
#elif USE_LIST
typedef std::stack< Type, std::list< Type > > StackType;
#else
typedef std::stack< Type, std::deque< Type > > StackType;
#endif

int main() {
    StackType mystack;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100 * 1024; ++i ) {
        mystack.push( i );
    }
    assert( mystack.size() == 100 * 1024 );
    return 0;
}
```

Execution comparison:

```
$ g++ -DUSE_VECTOR stack.cpp -o stack; time ./stack

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.031s

$ g++ -DUSE_LIST stack.cpp -o stack; time ./stack

real    0m0.144s
user    0m0.186s
sys     0m0.030s

$ g++  stack.cpp -o stack; time ./stack

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.015s

asaha@nedata8 ~/code
$
```

The above numbers are result of single run. **To achieve statistically significant numbers run each variation large number of times, and observe the mean and standard deviation.**

Apparently, `deque` and `vector` results in similar performance, whereas `list` is worse.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, custom sequences are okay, as long as they support `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_front()`. Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00693.html#_details

Answer (score 8):

10K what?  Most std::stack implementations could easily handle 10K primitives with good performance, since that's probably < 80KB.  However, the standard doesn't guarantee performance.

Also note that it depends what backend you use.  The default is std::deque, which is basically an array of arrays.  However, you should get decent performance with any backend.

Comment: std::deque is most commonly implemented as an array of arrays.  A list of arrays would not meet the complexity requirements set forth in the standard.

Answer (score 5):

A `std::stack` is only limited by the underlying container (a `std::stack` is a container adapter).

Depending on what the underlying container is, you'll have different limits.

A `std::vector` will require contiguous memory whereas a `std::list` will only be limited by the size of the heap (and possibly any heap fragmentation).  But `std::deque` (the default container) is between the two; it requires smaller chunks of contiguous memory but will primarily be limited by the size of the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can handle 10k.   As long as you have the memory resources for it.  If you are worried it uses the internal stack,  it doesn't.

Performance is implementation specific, but should be very quick

Comment: A stack overflow is a little confusing in this context... If you mean that your std::stack may overflow, then yes, it's possible, but that would mean your system has completely run out of memory, which is unlikely given the 10K figure. As for an overflow of the execution stack, that would not apply in this case as you are dealing with dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

std::stack is not a container, but a container adapter. By default it uses an std::deque as container, but you can also use a std::vector or std::list. Deques free their memory when elements are removed.

Comment: The default container is `std::deque`